# jQuery on change and on load solution

Tags: jquery

I am trying to stream-line some code that I believe is a little sloppy. Basically a script that checks to see the value of a select box and shows or hides a div based on the value selected. I want to check the value on load as well as on change. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

```
// Required items  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
 if($("#credentials").attr("selectedIndex") == "None") {
    $('#CDiv').show();
 }else{
     $('#CDiv').hide();
   }
 $("#credentials").change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == "None" ) {
        $('#CDiv').show();     
    } else {
        $('#CDiv').hide();      
        }  
    });    
});
```

I appreciate any help with this. I am still a little green on jQuery. Thanks!

Comment: `selectedIndex` is a property not an attribute and it doesn't return "None".

Comment: hmmm. This actually works. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`selectedIndex` is a property not an attribute and it doesn't return "None". If you want to read it's value you should use `prop` method instead. That being said you can trigger the change event instead of using `if` statement.  By triggering the event your `change` handler is executed once on DOM ready:

```
$("#credentials").on('change', function() {
    $('#CDiv').toggle( this.value === 'None' ); 
}).change();
```