# JS trigger value check on change AND on load for an element added to page after document load

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's happening is this:

1. User hits button to add input field
2. When that input field changes to have a value > 0, a function is fired that adds another input field

The code works fine as below and in Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9nf6r3xf/1/

```
$("#add").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".content").append(
    '<input class="input" type="number" min="0" />'
  )
})

$(document).on("change", ".input", function() {
  if ($(this).val() > 0) {
    $(".add-content").append(
      '<input class="input" type="text" value="test" />'
    )
  }
})
```

The additional complexity however, is I realized in SOME situations, the user will add an input field ALREADY containing a value. In that case, I STILL want the `change` function to run, and the second input field to be added. In other words, I want the `change` function to run if the `click` function appends like this:

```
 $(".content").append(
   '<input class="input" type="number" min="0" value="3"/>'
 )
```

I've read these answers ([jQuery on change and on load solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20889231/jquery-on-change-and-on-load-solution), [How to get option value on change AND on page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24121195/how-to-get-option-value-on-change-and-on-page-load)), which suggest to trigger a change event immediately on my change function, like this:

```
$(".input").change(function(){
   if ($(this).val() > 0) {
     $(".add-content").append(
       '<input class="input" type="text" value="test" />'
     )
   }
}).change()
```

However, that solution will not work for me, because since `.input` is itself added by a JS button click event, I need to add my listener to the document, hence `$(document).on("change", ".input")` instead of `$(".input").change()`

---

**FINAL WORKING ANSWER FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/9nf6r3xf/7/**

took the selected answer and made a modification to build some flexibility in because I will ultimately be using this on more than one field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should be as simple as triggering a click event on the dynamically added `input` right after you append it.

So what you have now is this in your click event handler

`$(".content").append(
    '<input class="input" type="number" min="0" />'
  )`

Add this line after it

`$(".content > .input:last").trigger("change")`

So the idea is to find the last element with class `input` 
By using the `:last` selector (as the element added using `append` will be in last) and triggering a `click` event on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom event to call when element is appended to `document` having the same handler as `change` event; `.trigger()` to call `"_change"` custom event on `:last` `.input` element appended to `.content` container element

```js
$("#add").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".content").append(
    '<input class="input" type="number" min="0" />'
  )
})
// adjusted selector to `.input:last` to prevent
// handler being called for each `.input` element
$(document).on("change _change", ".input:last", function(e) {
  if ($(this).val() > 0) {
    $(".add-content").append(
      '<input class="input" type="text" value="test" />'
    )
  }
})

// add `.input` element to `.content` having `value` set to `3`, 
$(".content").append(
    '<input class="input" type="number" min="0" value="3"/>'
)
// trigger `"_change"` event on `.input:last`
.find(".input:last").trigger("_change")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<button id="add">
  Add
</button>
<span class="content">
</span>
<span class="add-content">
</span>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9nf6r3xf/5/